# why are some records being updated while others are not in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i am trying to update a table using a cursor. but only some records were updated and others are not updated.the where clause of the update query has a column with index. can you please explain why and what to do regarding this issue?

```
update table_name 
set table_column1='text' 
where table_column2=(select distinct table_column2 from table);
```

index is on table_column2.

Comment: Is that a type? Should `table` be `table_name`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the where sub query?  And why are you using distinct?  Distinct should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: @Ramesh K- If `table` and `table_name` are different tables, are you sure that `table` has every value of `table_column2` that exists in `table_name`?  Can either table have `NULL` values in `table_column2`?

Comment: You should probably be using `IN` instead of `=` on the sub query.

Comment: If your table has more than 1 distinct `table_column2` value, you should get `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row`

Comment: You say you're using a cursor, but the "code" you've shown doesn't have anything to do with an (explicit) cursor.  Is there something relevant you're not showing?

Comment: You are asking us to play "Spot the bug" without posting your whole code or sample data (input *and* output).  That's not fair.

Comment: Run the sub query and find how may rows are returned. If more than one row is returned, change  = symbol with `in` in the update statement

Answer (score 0):

Let's take some educated guesses.  If you execute SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_COLUMN2 FROM TABLE by itself I suspect you'll find that you only get back a single value, and that the rows in TABLE_NAME which have TABLE_COLUMN2 equal to the value returned from the DISTINCT query were the ones which were updated.  This is perhaps a case where your expectations differ from the data in your database.  I believe this must be the case because if the DISTINCT query returned more than one value Oracle would throw an error (as mentioned in @a1ex07's comment above).  You might want to rewrite your query to use an IN condition, as

```
update table_name
  set table_column1='text'
  where table_column2 IN (select distinct table_column2 from table)
```

The index on TABLE_COLUMN2 should have no effect on the behavior of the UPDATE statement.

Share and enjoy.